# NameError: global name 'find' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, find, match, global

I'm a newbie of python.
Now I'm struggling with python.

I want to limit the region (longitude and latitude)

```
i = find((D[:, 2] >= -120.) 
          & (D[:, 2] <= -110.) 
          & (D[:, 3] >= -75.) 
          & (D[:, 3] <= -71.))
```

But Error occurred.

```
---> 21     i = find((D[:, 2]>=-120.) & (D[:, 2]<=-110.) & (D[:, 3]>=-75.) & (D[:, 3]<=-71.))
     22     MN = mean(D[i, :], axis=0)
     23     STD = std(D[i, :], axis=0, ddof=1)
NameError: global name 'find' is not defined
```

Why this error occurred? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, where are you expecting `find` to have come from? It isn't in the [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), so what have you imported?

Comment: This looks like how you would use the MatLab find() function; have you recently come from a MatLab or Octave background?

Comment: Are you trying to do this: `D[(D[:, 2]>=-120.) & (D[:, 2]<=-110.) & (D[:, 3]>=-75.) & (D[:, 3]<=-71.)]`?